# Iteration over a object in php is not working correctly

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I have been struggling to get the iteration working of a objects array in php. I have a array structure like this:

```
Array
(

[0] => stdClass Object

(
        [tid] => 7
        [vid] => 2
        [name] => Bakkerijen
        [description] => 
        [format] => full_html
        [weight] => 0
        [depth] => 0
        [parents] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 10
        [vid] => 2
        [name] => Horeca
        [description] => 
        [format] => full_html
        [weight] => 1
        [depth] => 0
        [parents] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 8
        [vid] => 2
        [name] => Food Shops
        [description] => 
        [format] => full_html
        [weight] => 2
        [depth] => 0
        [parents] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )
```

)

I want to add a selected class to li if a value matches to tid within this array.

Here is the code and HTML I did for that:

```
 <?php $current_tid = 7; ?>
 <?php foreach ($terms as $term): ?>
              <?php unset($term->parents); ?> 
                <?php if($term->tid == $current_tid) { ?>
                <li><a href="/portfolio#filter=.tid-<?php print $term->tid; ?>" class="selected"><?php print $term->name;?></li>
                <?php }else if($term->tid != $current_tid){ ?>
                <li><a href="/portfolio#filter=.tid-<?php print $term->tid; ?>"><?php print $term->name; ?></a></li>

                <?php } ?>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the final output I am getting:

```
<ul class="cathome-list-inner">                            
<li>
    <a class="selected" href="/portfolio#filter=.tid-7">Bakkerijen</a>
</li>
<a class="selected" href="/portfolio#filter=.tid-7"></a>
<li>
    <a class="selected" href="/portfolio#filter=.tid-7"></a>
    <a href="/portfolio#filter=.tid-10">Horeca</a>
</li>                                          
<li>
    <a href="/portfolio#filter=.tid-8">Food Shops</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="/portfolio#filter=.tid-9">Non-food Shops</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="/portfolio#filter=.tid-11">Privé interieurprojecten</a>
</li>
```

The issue is why I am getting extra anchor tag added with the selected class..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
<li><a href="/portfolio#filter=.tid-<?php print $term->tid; ?>" class="selected"><?php print $term->name;?></li>
```

You are missing your closing `</a>` the browser is probably trying to automatically correct your mistake.

Comment: Thanks mate.. I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake :(

Comment: Happens to the best (and worst) of us.